# Meu projeto não sob no git, fica na branch local

Tags: visual-studio, git, repository

Criei uma branch e quando comitei minhas alterações, ficaram tudo na branch local. Não estou conseguindo subir pro repositório do git. O que fazer? Fiz um novo download do projeto e mantive um backup do projeto alterado, mas creio que a branch contem as alterações feitas. Botão direito na branch e selecionei **Enviar por push** e quando abro o repositório meu push não aparece. Como eu envio para o repositório?

Uso Bitbucket.

ao dar um git staus, obtenho isso:

> fatal: No a git repository(or any of the parent directories).git

Comment: Onde está armazenando? Bitbucket, GitHub? Configurou as chaves para acesso?

Comment: @TiagoTiede, BitBucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente não foi inicializado o git no diretório do seu projeto. Clone o projeto na sua máquina, configure corretamente o usuário e o e-mail com o git config e tente novamente.

Depois disso, use:

```
$ git branch -a
```

Este comando vai verificar se você tem branchs remotos. Se tiver, defina-os na sua máquina local com o comando:

```
$ git checkout <NOME_DO_BRANCH>
```

Aí é só 'commit' e 'push'. :)